# merging JSON Array with object - Rails 4- Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am using Rails 4 and got following JSON output from different sources

**source1**

```
@something1 =   book.find().to_json
```

output

```
"[{\"a\": \"val1\"}]"
```

**source2**

```
@something2 =   Author.where(title: :autitle).pluck(:val2).to_json
```

Output

```
"[{\"b\": \"val2\"}]"
```

**source 3**

```
@something3 = Publications.find_by_pub_id(id)
```

Output

```
{ 
  "c":"val3",
  "d":" val4"
}
```

I want the final output like

```
{
  "a": "val1",
  "b": "val2",
  "c":"val3",
  "d":" val4"
}
```

I have used merge like

```
@newval= @something1[0].merge(@something2[0]).merge(@something3)
```

But, it gives error

> undefined method merge!

Those variables are inside index method like

```
class Test controller < api::controller
  def index
   @something1 = ..
   @something2 = ..
   @something3 = ..
  end
end
```

Hope it is clear.

Comment: Can you include the complete log/error message? With the provided examples [Ursus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567464/6136634) works fine (you can see it in action [here](https://repl.it/KB2T/0)), so maybe you are getting different outputs in the `@something` variables.

Comment: @Gerry while that example is nice (and functional) maybe we should be clear that the **output** in the question is inaccurate. JSON is a `String` and thus the correct output for the first example is actually `"[{\"a\":\"val1\"}]"`. `String` does not have a `merge` method which would have been more obvious had the OP posted the full message. e.g. `undefined method merge! for "[{\"a\":\"val1\"}]":String`   *editted question for correct output*

Comment: @Khoga remove the `to_json` calls from the first 2 and add it to the end of the merge chain. See [Updated version of @Gerry's repl](https://repl.it/KB2T/2)

Comment: @engineersmnky You are right, i completely missed (ignored?) the `to_json`, so now it makes sense. Thank you for claryfing it.

Comment: @engineersmnky Maybe you should add an answer, yours is the correct solution.

Comment: @Gerry very well seems there might be other rails issues anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that JSON is a `String` thus

```
@something1 =   book.find().to_json
#=> "[{\"a\": \"val1\"}]"
```

This will make it far more difficult to deal with when trying to "merge" them together.

The error you are receiving is because `String` does not have a `merge` method (Next time please post the full error or at least the object reference) e.g. `undefined method merge! for "[{\"a\":\"val1\"}]":String`

Luckily the fix is extremely simple just remove `to_json` from the original 2 calls as such

```
require 'json'

@something1 = [{"a": "val1"}] # no to_json
@something2 = [{"b": "val2"}] # no to_json
@something3 = { "c": "val3", "d": " val4" } # no to_json

@something1[0].merge(@something2[0]).merge(@something3).to_json
#=> "{\"a\":\"val1\",\"b\":\"val2\",\"c\":\"val3\",\"d\":\" val4\"}"
```

See [Example](https://repl.it/KB2T/2) (based on @Gerry's original commented example)

Since this appears rails like we can probably simplify this whole process if we understood the relation ship between `Book`, `Author` and `Publication` eg.

```
Book.find().to_json(include: [:author,:publications]) 
# Or 
Book.find().to_json(include: [{author: {only: :name}},:publications])
```

This will avoid the need to merge as I fear the original example might actually need to be

```
@something1 =   book.find()
@something2 =   book.author
@something3 =   book.publications

@something1.attributes.merge({author: @something2.attributes,
    publications: @something3.map(&:attributes)}).to_json
```

Answer (score 2):

With no more information this seems enough

```
@something1[0].merge(@something2[0]).merge(@something3)
{
    :a => "val1",
    :b => "val2",
    :c => "val3",
    :d => " val4"
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like:

```
def mergejson(*args)
  merged = {}
  args.each do |a|
    merged.merge!(a.is_a?(Hash) ? a : a.first)
    # or use .deep_merge! if the hashes can contain nested hashes
  end
  return merged
end

irb(main):025:0> test = mergejson(something1, something2, something3)
=> {:a=>"val1", :b=>"val2", :c=>"val3", :d=>"val4"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also worked by:

```
@something1.first.merge(@something2.first).merge(@something3)

#=>{:a => "val1",:b => "val2",:c => "val3",:d => " val4"}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same answer as the [one provided by Ursus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567464/6136634).